# Discord.js - Removed channels are still visible on the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am currently writing a custom support ticket tool for a Discord with over 70k members, which spawns one category and three child-channels when a moderator investigates a ticket/report.

When the moderator is finished with the report, the created category and channels self-clean and get removed again. Though in some cases, these channels are still visible for the moderator even though they are, in fact, deleted.

I presume this is a caching issue on the client-side as every time the solution seems to be to reload the Discord client (ctrl+r). I am therefore wondering if there is something I can do code-wise that would avoid such issue.

Moderation happens around the clock and I can see this getting both annoying and looks like bad design for the customer if these channels keep on growing exponentially over-time.

A snippet of the self-cleaning function can be found below:

```js
module.exports.cleanChannels = async (client, guild_id, channel) => {
    await client.guilds.cache.get(guild_id).channels.cache.get(channel.parentID).children.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
    await client.guilds.cache.get(guild_id).channels.cache.get(channel.parentID).delete()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will mark this question as resolved. I am confident that we are looking at a client-side caching issue which is not solvable through the Discord bot.

The only seemingly alternative is to take a wholly different approach. By using a  continuous feed as opposed to spawning and deleting private channels, its possible to circumvent the caching issue presented above.

Answer (score -1):

I have something wierd too because the api can read a channel but when I try to do something special with it like deleting it will result in a error.

This channel should be deleted but is still in the api for some reason and cannot delete this channel annymore... its very annoying to say the least.

Comment: Please do not use answers as "me too" responses.  If it doesn't answer the question, it's not an answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33406066)